# Meteor + Nginx: Websocket connection stops working after the first request

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, nginx, deployment, websocket

I deployed my Meteor app on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx. I'm getting error that seems to be related to websocket configuration, specifically that

1. client is listening actively for changes but server only sends (or replies) to the very first connection and then subsequently does not update the client.
2. meteor server seems to halt once it receives a single request from the client.

On my development machine everything works fine, server is working and I can have multiple clients (browsers) connected - all on the same machine. But once I deploy on hosted Ubuntu with Nginx and try to connect from remote local, it just stops working after first connection.

This is my nginx config:

```
server_tokens off; 

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80 ; 
    server_name my-server.net; 

    root /var/www/appRoot/; 
    index index.html index.htm; 

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

Nginx access log:

```
==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
<local-public-ip> - - [15/Jun/2016:05:12:39 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 598 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
<local-public-ip> - - [15/Jun/2016:05:12:39 -0400] "GET /a25b83093e0a4c316f170b184b33fabceb024100.css?meteor_css_resource=true HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://lice.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
<local-public-ip> - - [15/Jun/2016:05:12:39 -0400] "GET /704ef5bcce37e3c58ad691371641883b2f9199cb.js?meteor_js_resource=true HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://lice.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
<local-public-ip> - - [15/Jun/2016:05:12:40 -0400] "GET /sockjs/info?cb=ea7eki4rlg HTTP/1.1" 200 89 "http://lice.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
<local-public-ip> - - [15/Jun/2016:05:13:20 -0400] "GET /sockjs/info?cb=7wm0hgbigi HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://lice.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
<local-public-ip> - - [15/Jun/2016:05:13:28 -0400] "GET /sockjs/info?cb=i764h9t6j0 HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://lice.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
```

3. Immediately after the first connection, my meteor server stops outputting anything on the server console - I think this indicates that something is waiting or blocking the javascript event loop.

I think this error is due to nginx configuration, specifically socketjs connection between nginx and browser client or proxying properly from nginx to meteor app or all three.

Edit: Not sure if this is relevant, but the server app was built on the server using "Meteor build" command after a git pull.

Comment: Were you able to resolve? I'm experiencing the same issue now

Comment: @JoshJoe No wasn't able to resolve it. I gave up and used mup deploy instead.